# Error in a NxtJS app when running: npm run build

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-realtime-database, next.js

In a NxtJS app (using Firebase with a Realtime database) I am working on I have the following issue, with this code:

```
const [dataRcdArray, setDataRcdArray] = useState([])
const [title, setTitle] = useState('')

useEffect(() => {
    firebase.database().ref(name+'/'+theKey)
    .once("value", snapshot => {
        // The next line avoids displaying multiple times the list, when reloading the page.
  setTitle(snapshot.child('Title').val())
        setDataRcdArray([])
  let itmNbr = 1;
  while (true) {
      let tmpNbrStr = 'Item_'+itmNbr.toString().padStart(2,'0')
      if (!snapshot.child(tmpNbrStr).exists().valueOf()) break
      setDataRcdArray(arr => [...arr, snapshot.child(tmpNbrStr).val()])
      const word = snapshot.child(tmpNbrStr).val()
      tmpNbrStr = 'Gender_'+itmNbr.toString().padStart(2,'0')
      const gender = snapshot.child(tmpNbrStr).val()
      tmpNbrStr = 'Translat_'+itmNbr.toString().padStart(2,'0')
      const translation = snapshot.child(tmpNbrStr).val()
      setDataRcdArray(arr => [...arr, {
          word: word,
          gender: gender,
          translation: translation
      }])
      itmNbr++
  }
    });
}, [])
```

When running this command:

```
% npm run dev
```

The app including the code above runs locally as expected without any problem.

But  when running:

```
% npm run build
```

I get the following error message:

```
info  - Linting and checking validity of types ...Failed to compile.

info  - Linting and checking validity of types ../app/components/colnDetails.tsx:27:27
Type error: Argument of type '(arr: never[]) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type '(arr: never[]) => any[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: never[]) => never[]'.
    Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
      Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.

  25 |           let tmpNbrStr = 'Item_'+itmNbr.toString().padStart(2,'0')
  26 |           if (!snapshot.child(tmpNbrStr).exists().valueOf()) break
> 27 |           setDataRcdArray(arr => [...arr, snapshot.child(tmpNbrStr).val()])
     |                           ^
  28 |           const word = snapshot.child(tmpNbrStr).val()
  29 |           tmpNbrStr = 'Gender_'+itmNbr.toString().padStart(2,'0')
  30 |           const gender = snapshot.child(tmpNbrStr).val()

Failed to compile.
```

Searching the net seems to indicate that I should be explicitly setting some types, but it is not clear.

How can I update my code to avoid this issue ?